# How can I seal a slate floor for long term protection?

Tags: flooring, sealing

I've recently purchased a house in Philadelphia which has a pretty humid basement split into a finished part, and an unfinished (workshop) part. The finished part has a slate floor that seems in reasonable condition, but it is requires some grouting. In a few places there are loose tiles and a few small parts where a layer from the corner of a slate tile has come off.

I suspect the previous owner may not have a performed any recent maintenance or sealing. I'm probably going to get a specialist, but what should I be looking for in terms of products and approaches to sealing this floor? I'd prefer to keep a more natural look. Given the hot and humid weather here in Philly I suspect I'll need to wait until spring or fall to do this work as the basement is my office space.

Answer (score 2):

If you're regrouting I highly recommend epoxy grout.  It's impermeable and doesn't have to be sealed.  I'm never using regular grout again.  I've done some myself, and have also asked pro tile setters to use it even if they haven't before, and haven't had problems with that.

[Here's the post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190903005427/http://emptormaven.com/2010/10/grout-i-can-live-with/) that turned me on to it for more info on market options